# How to avoid duplicate network calls in an Rx stream?

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive, rx-java2

I have the following stream.

```
Observable.just(Unit) // execute immediately
    .mergeWith(tryAgainRelay) // execute again when this relay emits
    .flatMap {
      api.call() // emits sealed class single containing `Success` or `Error` state
          .toObservable()
          .startWith(Loading) // emit loading (same sealed class as above)
    }
```

However, I never want duplicate (simultaneous) network calls (inner flatmap). If the `tryAgainRelay` emits while a network call is already in flight, I want this emissions to be discarded. I can avoid them with the following code:

```
var isLoading = false // track whether api call is in flight
Observable.just(Unit)
    .mergeWith(tryAgainRelay)
    .filter { isLoading.not() } // prevent emissions if api call is already in flight
    .flatMap {
      api.call()
          .toObservable()
          .startWith(Loading)
          // update state variable
          .doOnNext {
            isLoading = when (it) {
              Loading -> true
              is Error, is Success -> false
            }
          }
        }
```

It's a bit ugly, and involves stepping outside the stream with a `.doOnNext()`. Is there a better, more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: can you use `retry` on the api call instead?

Comment: How would retry help? That only affects onError, right?

Comment: "If the tryAgainRelay emits while a network call is already in flight, I want this emissions to be discarded" looks to me that you should try to use the `skipUntil` operator. But probably you will have to share the emissions of the `api.call().toObservable()`

Comment: Use ```switchMap()``` operator instead ```flatMap()```.

Comment: @RafaelGuillen no. `switchMap` would have a new network request replace an in progress request. I want new requests to be discarded while a request is already in progress

Comment: @masp I'm not actually sure how to do that

Comment: Have you try flowable Like request(1)? Or use Zip to control your call. It's just a thought, i didn't try it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`.

The retries will be created sequentially "queued" one after the other, so you can be sure that only one request will be executed in parallel (the next request will start when the previous one finishes - complete or error - **and** if `tryAgainRelay` has emitted).